# php convert dateobject format EX. **/Date(1084640400000+0700)/**

Tags: php

I have a datetime in the following String format:

```
/Date(1084640400000+0700)/
```

and I want to convert in format `yyyy-mm-dd` to insert and update MySQL 
by php.

Please recommend how do it.

Comment: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('1084640400000+0700'))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$timestamp=1084640400000+0700;
echo gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $timestamp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i have solution this

```
$str = $strDate;
    $match = preg_match('/\/Date\((\d+)([-+])(\d+)\)\//', $str, $date);
    print_r($date);


    $timestamp = $date[1]/1000;
    $operator = $date[2];
    $hours = $date[3]/100*3600;
    //$hours = substr($date[3],0,-2); // Get the seconds
    // echo "<br/>".$hours."<br/>";
    //print_r($timestamp);

    $datetime = new DateTime();

    $datetime->setTimestamp($timestamp);
    $datetime->modify($operator . $hours . ' seconds');

    var_dump( $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```